# Huffman Code with equal symbol frequencies

Tags: huffman-code

Starting with these frequencies:

A:7 F:6 H:1 M:2 N:4 U:5

at a later step I have 5 6 7 7, where one of the 7's is the "A". Which 7 branch I pick to be a 0 or a 1 is arbitrary.

So how do I get uniquely decodable code word?

Comment: If you're expecting an answer, you'd have to ask a much more complete question, including what you have tried and what happened that you need help with. You are positing some midpoint in the process of applying the Huffman algorithm, with no information on if or how you got stuck there, and if or how you ran into a problem generating code words.

Comment: step 1    H:1  M:2  N:4  U:5  F:6  A:7   step2       5 6 7 7  next step we have duplicate value 7 ,can we take any 7 as "A"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to send the code to the receiver, not the frequencies. You can arbitrarily assign `0`'s and `1`'s to all of the branches, and then send the codes for each symbol before the coded symbols themselves. There are many possible Huffman codes from the same set of frequencies.

More commonly only the code lengths in bits for each symbol are sent. In this case those are `A:2 F:2 H:4 M:4 N:3 U:2`. Then a [canonical code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canonical_Huffman_code) is used on both ends that depends only on the lengths. In this case, starting with `0`'s, the canonical code would be:

```
A: 00
F: 01
U: 10
N: 110
H: 1110
M: 1111
```

where codes of equal length are assigned to the symbols in lexicographical order. Note that the Huffman tree that was built is not needed. All that is needed is the number of bits for each symbol.